# Query property for models in sqlalchemy 1.4-2.0

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When we are using Flask we know, that we can declare our models and either map them for INSERTS *or map SELECT results into these models.*

For example, we can do something like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sample.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean) 
    def __init__(id, name, password, admin):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.admin = admin

@app.route('/user', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_users(current_user):       
    users = User.query.all()
    ...
```

Here in `users` we do not query our data like it's written in the official docs:

```
session.query(User).all()
```

Just `User.query.all()` and it's perfect - we get all we need. It's so amazing, isn't it?!

For applying this option in any other (not-Flask) project we can do smth like that:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Connect:
    engine = create_engine(conf.DATABASE_URI)
    DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    session = DBSession()


class Query(Connect):
    query = Connect.DBSession.query_property()


class User(Base, Query):
     ...
```

That will bring us to the same behaviour of the our User-model. We are able to query just from the model and map the results into it. Updates, deletes, `Model.query.get(<your_primary_key>)` - anything is available.

To my mind it's so great that I can't imagine my coding without it.
But when we are facing ASYNC versions of ORMs, engines and so on it appears that either we have to make raw sql-queries or use long-length code.

I've read docs for SQLAlchemy 1.4-2.0 and failed to find any possibility of applying above mentioned querying style to asynchronuous coding. Even if we are going to use

```
await AsyncSession(bind=async_engine).run_sync(function_quering_smth)
```

it seems impossible to implement it.

So, please, tell me: am I right and it is really impossible and nothing can be done OR am I wrong, and there is a way?